# How can a webserver do images like this?

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation

Below is a thumbnail type image that is on a post from http://doctype.com/, if you haven't been on the site yet, it is similar to this site but for css/design stuff and when you post a question you can have it post a screenshot image as well for you of a website url.

Below is one of them I saw, do you think this is something done programmticly?

IF so how would you do this server side?

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [doctype.com](http://media.doctype.com/1f0be842-b2f3-4e11-a0ac-9dc72cb50a67.png))</sub>

Comment: Seems like a more fitting question to ask over there, or look at the HTML source of such a page. How about an actual link to an example on that site?

Comment: @Matt Ball I disagree. This is a image manipulation question, which is as much a programing problem as any of the other [image-processing] [image-manipulation] questions.

Comment: As a note, doctype.com closed as of February 15, 2013. [Read more about it](http://blog.doctype.com/doctype_is_closing_on_the_14th_1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this *screenshot-in-a-note* effect by having a template image of the curled-paperclipped-note (the curled border, the paper clip, the shadow) and a mask for where the screenshot of the site should fit inside the template. Once you get the screenshot you just rotate it slightly and compose it with the template.

To compose it programmatically you could use ImageMagick as [sugested by cpharmston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300182/how-can-a-webserver-do-images-like-this/1300201#1300201).

Here's an alternative of how to compose the two images with [PIL and python](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2007-April/004381.html).

Answer (score 1):

If it is done programmatically, it likely uses an image processing library. [GD](http://www.php.net/gd) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) are two of the more popular ones.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to do it programmatically on the server.  There are some flash plugins to do it, but I think server side is the way to go.
This is how I did it:
http://www.guangmingsoft.net/htmlsnapshot/html2image.htm
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php